# Which best algorithm for my list management?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am struggling with one algorithm. I want to do some actions ( update, delete, add elements) on the current list from data sumbitted one the second list.

My first list `currentList` and the submitted List `submittedList`

The problem i have to resolve is that:

1. If a element of the currentList is in the submittedList, this element must be updated in the currentList
2. If a element of the currentList is not in the submittedList, this element must be delete from the currentList
3. All the  a element of the submittedList that are not in the currentList must be add to the currentList

If you could help please, thanks

Comment: `List` has methods `contains`, `add`, and `remove`. Use them to check if an element exists and to insert and delete elements.

Comment: Are these elements unique ? It looks like these operations would work a lot faster it they were made on sets instead of lists

Comment: Can you just throw away `currentList` and use `submittedList`? If not, can you just `clear` `currentList` and `addAll` the contents of `submittedList` to `currentList`?

Comment: Even if the new value is a combination of the currentList and submittedList values, base the scan on submittedList. It has exactly the elements you want in the new currentList.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The problem is that in the case of update i have to update some properties of elements and not delete and insert element. Element have links to other objects.

Comment: How do you decide if an element is "on the list"? Does it have something like a primary key? If so, you might be better off with a `Map<Key,Element>` rather than a `List`.

Comment: Element have an identifier ( not the id from database). The equality is made on another property

Answer (score 1):

Think this in a different way. You need the currentList to have only objects in submittedList, but just need to modify the object if its present in both the lists. So your algorithm has only two steps.

My suggestion would be to go with a temporary list. I have added a solution below assuming that the objects in your lists are Strings. (You can replace String with your custom object)

```
List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String test : submittedList) {
    if(currentList.contains(test)) {
        String test1 = test+"xyz"; // do modification to test String
        tempList.add(test1);
    } else {
        tempList.add(test);
    }
}
currentList.clear(); // Now add to the actual list after clearing
currentList.addAll(tempList);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that while iterating you will add element even if it match with the second element of the submittedList.

Comment: Oh..so your list has duplicates. Then its better to convert your List to a Set and execute this logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, sort both lists. Then scan them in increasing order: read the first elements `c` and `s` from `currentList` and `submittedList`. If `c==s`, update `c` and get the next `c` and `s`; if `c<s` (meaning that `c` is not in `submittedList`), discard `c` from `currentList` and get the next `c`; if `c>s` (meaning that `s` is not in `currentList`), insert `s` in `currentList` and get the next `s`. And so on.

When one of the list is exhausted, continue with the rules `c<*` and `*>s`. Stop when both lists are exhausted.